# Custom Template Help

Tags: theming, 7

I am making a custom module on Drupal 7 and I am into to use templates for showing the info. How can I pass values from the module to the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, You need to use theme() function, which will allow to define the template name to be called, and the variables (values) to be send over to the template file defined.
Please refer documentation here - https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7

```
$read_more = theme('more_link', array('url' => 'aggregator/sources/' . $feed->fid, 'title' => t("View this feed's recent news.")));
```

In the above code "more_link" is template name and associative array of values to be passed. In Template, you will get value of $title as "View this feed's recent news."
Hope you got the point.

Comment: Awesome! This worked perfect for me! Thanks you so much!